# Synchronisation problem with SharePoint Libraries and my local folders

Tags: sharepoint-online

Today i had an issue, my SharePoint libraries aren't synchronised with my local folders :

- If i create a folder on SP Library, it wouldn't appear in my local folder,
- If i create a folder on my local folder, it wouldn't appear in my SP Library.

Until i press Sync button in SP Library the problem would be solved, but the problem i have a lot of libraries sync with a lot of folder, how can i automate that without having to do it manually for each one ?

Comment: I assume you are using OneDrive for syncing. And as it affects all your libraries, have a try on fixes like reset your OneDrive:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-sharepoint-online-sync-problems-aaa2d172-8d45-4e94-9c04-5364d04ca2f4

Comment: And does this issue occur all of a sudden? By default OneDrive client shall sync automatically when there is a change in both sides, if this issue remains, you may better open a service request.